# 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, modelform

I am trying to set a field's choices in a modelform by overiding the **init**
but i get this error

```
 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

forms.py

```
class carOwnerForm(forms.ModelForm):
first_name = forms.charfield()
last_name = forms.charfield()

def __init__(self, a,b,c):
    super(carOwnerForm,self).__init(a,b,c)
    self.fields['ownership_Type'].choices = [(a,'c'),(b,'b'),(c,'x')]

class Meta:
    model = CarOwner
    fields = ['ownership_type','CarModel']
```

view

```
def CarOwnerSearch(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    form = carOwnerForm('B','None','C')
    return render (request,'carmanager/CarOwnerSearch.html', {'form': form})
```

error in the html

```
    Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/parcelmanager/CrownLandsSearch/
Django Version:     1.8
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Exception Location:     C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py in value_from_datadict, line 223





      Traceback:
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Sites\laisy\carmanager\views.py" in CrownLandsSearch
  811.         return render (request,'carmanager/CrownLandsSearch.html', {'form': form})
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  99.         return template.render(context, request)
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  74.         return self.template.render(context)
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  209.                     return self._render(context)
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  135.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render
  89.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  647.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  787.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  847.                             current = current()
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in as_p
  302.             errors_on_separate_row=True)
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in _html_output
  203.         top_errors = self.non_field_errors()  # Errors that should be displayed above all fields.
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in non_field_errors
  310.         return self.errors.get(NON_FIELD_ERRORS, self.error_class(error_class='nonfield'))
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in errors
  176.             self.full_clean()
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  392.         self._clean_fields()
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in _clean_fields
  401.             value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
File "C:\Users\yfevrier\Envs\landregtry1\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in value_from_datadict
  223.         return data.get(name, None)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /parcelmanager/carOwnerSearch/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Please check the indentions. At least its broken here on your example

Comment: The `data` variable is of type `str` hence the error. You can use `if name in data` to check if `name` exists in `data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do it to solve this problem...

your form.py

```
class CarOwnerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.charfield()
    last_name = forms.charfield()

    class Meta:
        model = CarOwner
        fields = ['ownership_type','CarModel']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        _choices_list = kwargs.pop('_choices', None)
        super(CarOwnerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if _choices_list is not None:
            # this only works if 'ownership_type' is a CharField... and it will be your error
            self.fields['ownership_type'].choice = _choices_list  # I don't remeber if the attribute is 'choice' or 'choices'
            # if 'ownership_type' is a RelationField, you must set queryset and not a list of strings
```

and in your views.py

```
...
def car_owner_search(request):
    """Doctype for view"""
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        _CHOICE_LIST = ['B', 'None', 'C']
        if request.method == 'POST':
             form = CarOwnerForm(data=request.POST, _choices=_CHOICE_LIST)

             if form.is_valid():
                your_model = form.save(commit=False)
                your_model.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
                your_model.save()
        else:
            form = CarOwnerForm(_choices=_CHOICE_LIST)
        return render (request,'carmanager/CarOwnerSearch.html', {'form': form})
    return HttpRedirect('/login/') # or other HttpResponse
```

Comment: thank you, with your help i was able to solve it!!!!!
i dont understand fully the init method and *args, *kwards
which should be agruements and dictionarys but thanks 
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are really quite a few errors here.

Firstly, modelforms expect a certain interface. They accept the POST, any initial data, and a model instance. But you've overridden that so that they only accept `a, b, c`, whatever that is; not only have you destroyed the ability of the class to do the things it needs to do, you also pass those arguments on to the superclass which isn't expecting them.

Secondly, you need to take more care with your attributes. Forms don't have a `field` attribute, they have `fields`; a choicefield doesn't have a `choice` attribute, it has `choices`; and choices needs to be a iterable of iterables, for IDs and display values, not a single iterable.

Comment: im sorry i made alot of mistakes my actual code has fields and choices i dunno why it dropped the 's'
what im looking for is the model has a set of choices but in a view i want only two out of the three and thought i had to override the init to make it display different chocies. 
 i also want when i dont provide agruements to load everything from the modelform